# How do I check if an image view has an image uploaded from the gallery in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, imageview

i have already checked imageView.getdrrawable()==null , but the imageview already contained source image so it is returning true? how to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Use getDrawable() method, if it return null then nothing assigned

```
if( mImageView.getDrawable() != null){

    //Image Assigned

    }else{

  //nothing assigned

  }
```

Comment: But i have already attached the source image that's why it is not returning false .. what to do now ?